# SQL max function returning NULL value

Tags: sql, sqlite

[Here's the DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRh8jZsVeiv2V3JdhbyZYn/0)

I'm trying to get the minimum, maximum, and average median household income in each state. Although i'm getting the Minimum and Average income. The maximum values are all returning NULL. Here's my code,

```
SELECT
Statecode,
MIN(Median_household_income) 'Minimum income',
MAX(Median_household_income) 'Maximum Income',
AVG(Median_household_income) 'Average Income'
FROM census
GROUP BY Statecode;
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query code is basically fine, but I would write it as:

```
SELECT
    Statecode,
    MIN(Median_household_income) as Minimumincome,
    MAX(Median_household_income) as MaximumIncome,
    AVG(Median_household_income) as AverageIncome
FROM census
GROUP BY Statecode;
```

Note:  No single quotes around the column names.  Only use single quotes for STRING and DATE/TIME constants.

The issue is your table creation.  SQLite is already confused enough about the types of columns (it basically ignores the declarations and stores whatever you put there).  Your code makes it worse, because you are confusing numbers and strings.  Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."census" ("Statecode", "Population", "Median_household_income")
    VALUES ('PR', '17800', '11507');
```

(I would also advise you to drop the double quotes.  They just make queries harder to write and to read.)

You have defined `Population` and `Median_household_income` as integers.  You should insert them as integers, not strings:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."census" ("Statecode", "Population", "Median_household_income")
    VALUES ('PR', 17800, 11507);
```

Later on, you have examples like this:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."census" ("Statecode", "Population", "Median_household_income")
VALUES ('MA', '237', 'NULL');
```

This confusion is even worse with `NULL`.  `NULL` and `'NULL'` are two very different things.  The first is a SQL constant that represents an unknown value (often used for missing values).  The second is a string with four characters, such as `'Ohio'` or `'love'`.  You intend `NULL`.

And, if you use that, the code will [work](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pS5qFa9HpbKUrRHRuSKJ3Y/0).  I am a bit confused as to why this returns a value for `MIN()`, but not for `MAX()` -- as I say, SQLite has quite confusing (to me) typing rules, so there is probably some reason.  However, if you stick with the correct types then you won't have this problem.

EDIT:

There seems to be a bug with SQLite and typing.  This expression -- shockingly -- returns `'text'` for `max()` and `'integer'` for `min()`:

```
select typeof(max("Median_household_income")), 
       typeof(min("Median_household_income"))
from census
```

SQLite has such arcane typing rules that this can happen.  The `MIN()` and `MAX()` are based on the ordering of the column.  The type appears to follow whatever the first or last type is based on the column ordering.

Comment: *I am a bit confused as to why this returns a value for MIN(), but not for MAX()* everything is there in the documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: There is no bug. Again, read the documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof

Comment: @forpas . . . Nothing in that documentation refers to any difference between `MIN()` and `MAX()` with respect to mixed type columns.  Perhaps I'm missing something, but I see no explanation for the different types in the documentation.  In fact, the documentation clearly states:  "Aggregate max() returns NULL if and only if there are no non-NULL values in the group."  And this example clearly shows that the documentation is incorrrecct.

Comment: In this example the OP does not get NULLs but 'NULL's. Isn't that clear?

Comment: I'm just surprised that the OP accepted your answer which is totally misleading.

Comment: *The type appears to follow whatever the first or last type is based on the column ordering* wrong again. MIN() and MAX() follow the data type comparison rules of SQLite which are explained clearly here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually your table contains values in the column `Median_household_income` with the string literal `'NULL'` and not `NULL`.
As it is explained in [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value

so you get the minimum integer value because it is less than `'NULL'` but for the maximum you get `'NULL'` and **not** `NULL` in the results.

Remove them with this statement (because I guess you don't want them):

```
UPDATE census 
SET Median_household_income = NULL
WHERE Median_household_income = 'NULL'
```

and the query will work fine.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRh8jZsVeiv2V3JdhbyZYn/1).
Results:

```
| Statecode | Minimum income | Maximum Income | Average Income |
| --------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| MA        | 2499           | 83273          | 57358          |
| PR        | 6989           | 66063          | 19598.656      |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have some illegal/overflowing/non-numeric value in your data at that column. Try filtering it out with this query

```
SELECT
Statecode,
MIN(Median_household_income) 'Minimum income',
MAX(Median_household_income) 'Maximum Income',
AVG(Median_household_income) 'Average Income'
FROM census
WHERE Median_household_income < 1000000
GROUP BY Statecode;
```

Which works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `NULL` text so, either remove it (using `where` clause) or updated it `null` value :

```
SELECT Statecode,
       MIN(Median_household_income) 'Minimum income',
       MAX(Median_household_income) 'Maximum Income',
       AVG(Median_household_income) 'Average Income'
FROM census
WHERE Median_household_income <> 'NULL'
GROUP BY Statecode;
```